# Unable to insert multi-language data in MySQL DB using a stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql

I am calling a stored procedure from my java code which has an insert query which takes data from one table and inserts into another. This insert query works perfectly fine if I run the query directly even with multi-language data, but when I run the stored procedure its giving issue while inserting multi-language or unicode data. Unable to understand the reason behind this. Plus its working in one of the database instances and not working in another.

1. I have already set the charset of both tables and their columns to 'utf8' and collation to 'utf8_general_ci'.
2. In both the database instances, variables are set as below:
   character_set_client: utf8mb4
   character_set_connection: utf8mb4
   character_set_database: utf8
   character_set_server: utf8mb4
   character_set_system: utf8
   character_set_results: utf8mb4
   collation_connection: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
   collation_database: utf8_general_ci
   collation_server: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Please let me know what could be the issue with stored procedure or any database settings.